# Keeping only update date based on column with vertical condition PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, window, palantir-foundry

I would like, for each ID, to select only updated records based on "A" column based on some conditions.

The use case is just one example. The following points serve to complicate the exercise for processing data vertically by adding these conditions:

1 - I wanna track all changements on column "A", keeping only the first occurrance of that value

2 - I wanna preserve *NULL* values

3 - "A" can be higher or lower or equal than the previous one

4 - I haven't a *dt_run* timestamp. So I want to assume that if within the same day I have different "A" values this is caused by not sortable of *dt_run*. If this day contains values equal to the previous and following we can delete them (assuming we can go directly to the next update [bold in the example]). If this day contains a different value then give it that value [italic in the example].

5 - My expected output is to have *ID-dt_run* just in one row.

`Input df`

| ID | A | dt_run |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 2022-02-11 |
| **1** | **72** | **2022-02-13** |
| **1** | **45** | **2022-02-13** |
| **1** | **72** | **2022-02-13** |
| 1 | 72 | 2022-02-15 |
| 1 | 45 | 2022-02-16 |
| 2 | 88 | 2022-02-16 |
| 2 | 88 | 2022-02-16 |
| *2* | *88* | *2022-02-17* |
| *2* | *77* | *2022-02-17* |
| *2* | *Null* | *2022-02-17* |
| 2 | Null | 2022-02-18 |
| 2 | 92 | 2022-02-19 |

---

`Desidered output`

| ID | A | dt_run |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 2022-02-11 |
| 1 | 72 | 2022-02-15 |
| 1 | 45 | 2022-02-16 |
| 2 | 88 | 2022-02-16 |
| 2 | 77 | 2022-02-17 |
| 2 | Null | 2022-02-18 |
| 2 | 92 | 2022-02-19 |

I tried to use several window functions that were too intricate. Is there an easy way to solve these vertical questions?

Thank u for your help!

Comment: Hi @jresearcher stackoverflow is not really a place to ask others to implement things for you. My Recommendation would be to edit your question identifying what you have tried and why it's not working

Comment: My question is general and is not aimed at a use case. The question is asked for the difficulty of working the data vertically.
I am close to a resolution that uses different windows but I was wondering if there was a faster way to work the data in this way.

Comment: Got it, since this is a pure data modeling and pyspark question, if no one answers here you may have some luck here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using window functions. See logic and code below

```
W=Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('dt_run')
new = (df.withColumn('x',row_number().over(W))#Create Row number for each ID
       .withColumn('y',max('x').over(Window.partitionBy('A','ID')))#Find maximum index in a combination of A and ID
       .where((col('x')==col('y'))|(col('x')==1))#Filter where index and maximum index are equal or the index is the first
       .orderBy('ID','dt_run')#reorder the frame
       .drop('x','y')#drop unwanted columns
      ).show(truncate=False)

+---+----+----------+
|ID |A   |dt_run    |
+---+----+----------+
|1  |45  |2022-02-11|
|1  |72  |2022-02-15|
|1  |45  |2022-02-16|
|2  |88  |2022-02-16|
|2  |77  |2022-02-17|
|2  |88  |2022-02-17|
|2  |null|2022-02-18|
|2  |92  |2022-02-19|
+---+----+----------+
```